# Is the possible to print elements in apostrophes with ','.join() and list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, string

mylist = ["apples", "bananas", "mangos"]

**Wanted output:**
"apples", "bananas", "mangos"

I've managed to print it this way but can't make it with apostrophes.

> > > print(','.join([x for x in mylist]))
> > > apples,bananas,mangos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> mylist = ["apples", "bananas", "mangos"]
>>> print(', '.join(['"' + x + '"' for x in mylist]))
"apples", "bananas", "mangos"
>>> print(repr(mylist).strip('[]'))
'apples', 'bananas', 'mangos'
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add quotes to beginning and end, like this

```
print('"'+'", "'.join(mylist)+'"')
```

Comment: your is working, mine wasn't, though can do it that way :-) 
>>> print('"',','.join([x for x in mylist]),'"')